# Play framework 2 save input fields when empty

Tags: playframework-2.0

There is an update function in the controller i use:

```
public static Result updateCustomer(Long id) {
    Form<CustomerData> customerDataForm = form(CustomerData.class)
            .bindFromRequest();

    if (customerDataForm.hasErrors()) {
        return badRequest(views.html.admin.customerFormEdit
                .render(customerDataForm));
    }
    customerDataForm.get().update(id);
    flash("success", "Customer " + customerDataForm.get().customerName
            + " has been updated");
    return CLIENT_HOME;
}
```

but it won't save empty input text values, not even the unticked checkboxes.

When i tick a checkbox, or input any value to any field it's saved on update, but if i want to save empty input or unticked checkbox it does not remove the previously saved value on update.

How can i solve this?

Comment: I think your `updateCustomer` function is fine. Can you provide your model and your view code please?

Answer (score 0):

Following example shows that we can save/update empty value of input or ticked/not ticked checkbox:

#### The Controller:

```java
public static Result editCustomer() {
    // find CustomerData, Note: this use hard coded ID
    CustomerData customerData = CustomerData.find.byId(1L); 
    Form<CustomerData> customerDataForm = Form.form(CustomerData.class)
        .fill(customerData);

    return ok(views.html.editCustomer.render(customerDataForm));
}

public static Result updateCustomer() {
    Form<CustomerData> customerDataForm = Form.form(CustomerData.class)
        .bindFromRequest();

    if (customerDataForm.hasErrors()) {
        return badRequest(editCustomer.render(customerDataForm));
    }
    CustomerData customerData = customerDataForm.get();

    // update data, Note: this use hard coded ID
    customerData.update(1L);
    flash("success", "Customer ID " + customerData.id + " has been updated");

    return redirect(routes.Application.editCustomer());
}
```

#### The Model:

```java
@Entity
public class CustomerData extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long id;
    public String name;
    public boolean isMember;

    public static Finder<Long, CustomerData> find = new Finder<>(
        Long.class, CustomerData.class
    );
}
```

#### The Views:

```scala
@(customerDataForm: Form[models.CustomerData])
@import views.html.helper._

@main(title = "Edit Customer Data") {
    @form(routes.Application.updateCustomer()) {
        @*** Note: this use hard coded ID ***@
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1">
        @inputText(customerDataForm("name"), 'label -> "Customer Name")
        @checkbox(customerDataForm("isMember"))

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    }
}
```

Hope this will be helpful. :)